# Forcing v.buffer distance units to be different from map proj units using GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, buffer, units

I'm not very familiar with GRASS GIS. I am working on MODIS data, and set the region to match the projection of the data, which is given in degree units. I need to create a buffer with a 250m distance, I tried to use as distance field 0:00:08.111518 (that is equal to the map resolution, that is 250m in my case), but it returns an empty map. I don't understand where is the mistake that I am doing,

What am I doing wrong?

I'd change the map units, if it can be done, but I don't know if it could mess the data up, therefore I was wondering if there is any method to force the unit of `v.buffer` to differ from the one of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a new location and setting the region to the EPSG that SENTINEL data use for my area of interest (unit is already meters there), and reprojecting all the data I needed. I don't know if this is the best way to deal with the issue, but it worked.
Looking forward to a feedback of a more expert user.

Comment: This is generally correct.  You do the analyses in the projection you need to work in.